# Calcular média por classes depois de excluir MIN e MAX

Tags: r

Encontrei algumas perguntas semelhantes, mas nenhuma com o mesmo problema que estou enfrentando.

Preciso calcular  a média por classes, porém antes de calcular cada média, gostaria de excluir os valores MAX e MIN de cada classe:

EXEMPLO:

```
classe <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 4)
valor <- c(10, 5, 7, 1, 19, 4, 2, 0)

dados <- data.frame(classe, valor)
  classe valor
1      A    10
2      A     5
3      A     7
4      A     1
5      B    19
6      B     4
7      B     2
8      B     0
```

Neste caso, para a classe A, os valores 10(max) e 1(min) seriam excluídos e então a média seria calculada: (5+7)/2 = 6.

Para simplesmente calcular a média por classes, eu estou usando o seguinte código:

```
aggregate(empresas$pL, list(setor = empresas$setor), mean)
```

Mas ainda preciso descobrir como excluir os MAXs e MINs

Comment: Se houver alguma classe com valores de máximo ou mínimo repetidos, é preciso excluir os dois? Por exemplo, suponha que a classe `A` fosse `10, 5, 7, 1, 10`. A média dela deveria ser `(5+7)/2 = 6` ou `(5+7+10)/3 = 7.3`?

Answer (score 3):

Eis duas maneiras de fazer o que a pergunta pede. O truque é usar `range` para obter de uma só vez os valores de `min` e de `max`.

```
tapply(dados$valor, dados$classe, function(x){
  mean(x[!x %in% range(x)], na.rm = TRUE)
})
#A B 
#6 3 

aggregate(valor ~ classe, dados, FUN = function(x){
  mean(x[!x %in% range(x)], na.rm = TRUE)
})
#  classe valor
#1      A     6
#2      B     3
```